# Make to_html() mobile friendly or "Is it possible to add custom <td> tag attributes in to_html(...)?"

Tags: python, html, pandas, mobile

I create an html-rendering of a table from a dataframe and I would like to make it mobile friendly. One solution I found would require adding attributes to the `<td>` tags for each column entry (as per this suggestion https://codemyui.com/pure-css-responsive-table/ of using a CSS file which decides when to switch from table view to a kind of list-view).

So basically I would like to get this code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'H1': [1,2], 'H2':[10,20]})
print(df.to_html())
```

to produce something like this:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td data-column="H1">1</td>
      <td data-column="H2">10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td data-column="H1">2</td>
      <td data-column="H2">20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If this is not the way to go I would be happy to hear any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (assuming it only goes up to `h2`):

```
tab_html = df.to_html()

ntd = tab_html.count("<td>")
tab_html = tab_html.replace('<td>', '<td data-column="H{}">')
colindex = [i%2 + 1 for i in range(ntd)]
print(tab_html.format(*colindex))
```

This will work as long as `h1` and `h2` are the same length and `{}` does not appear elsewhere in your html. If you want to increase the number of keys (say e.g. up to `h4`), just change the number in `i%2` to the number of keys.